# jQuery AJAX success issue

Tags: jquery

The following code snippet is returning 'failed' alert box even thought the form is filled out correctly, I would like to display the 'passed' alert box.
Surely there is something wrong but I can;t find where...

Full code here: http://alessandrosantese.com/Forms/Custom_Validation/Form-Validation-Plugin-AJAX.html

```
    submit.click(function(evt) {  
        evt.preventDefault();

        validate_form();

        $('form input:not(.submit, .email, .test)').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                add_color($(this), red);
            }
            else {
                add_color($(this), white);
            }

        });

        var data = form.serialize();

            // AJAX call
            $.ajax({
                url: 'process.php',
                type: "post",
                data: data,
                success: function(r){

                    if (r.success) {
                        alert('passed');
                    } else {
                        alert('failed');
                    }

                }
            });



    });
```

PHP code (very basic, for now just to get the AJAX success working)

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['f_name'];
  $l_name = $_POST['l_name'];
  $email1 = $_POST['email'];
  $email2 = $_POST['email_c'];
     $tel = $_POST['tel'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
     $url = $_POST['url'];
     $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];

echo "\n$name\n$l_name\n$email1\n$email2\n$tel\n$postcode\n$url\n$checkbox";


?>
```

I need to find a way to make sure that validate_form(); worked before the AJAX call itself.

Comment: it's returning "failed" because r.success is undefined

Comment: hi, ok I am still new to ajax, what makes it undefined then?

Comment: @Alex the fact you never defined it!  Your `echo` should be sending back JSON encoded data, not just a list of NL separated strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does validate_form return anything? If so, you can capture the the return value of your function `validate_form()` anywhere.

`validate_form()` must return a boolean value to indicate whether the form is valid. In each of your functions - `validateEmail()`, `checkPostCode()`, `checkURL()` return a boolean value based on whether those fields are valid. And rewrite `validate_form()` as

```
function validate_form()
{ 
    return (validateEmail() && checkPostCode() && checkURL());
}
```

I think you want something like this:

```
if(validate_form()) //if the form is valid
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        success: function(r){
            alert('passed')
            },
        error: function(r){
            alert('failed: ' + r.statusText);
    });
}
else
{
      alert('failed');
}
```

Comment: Hi there, just used this and it's giving me 'passed' even though the form is empty, I need to find a way to make sure that validate_form(); worked before the success or AJAX call itself...

Comment: answer has been edited. does `validate_form()` return anything?

Comment: nope that's the problem I think as well, as it stands it only validates the fields and that's it....

Comment: yup, you would need it to return something so that you would know whether to proceed or not with the ajax call. The success and error in the ajax call are just to indicate the success/failure of the ajax and not the form validation. check the edits.

Comment: It's coming passed now. Mark the question as answered, as I guess your problem is rectified.

Comment: Hi just a little thing, on the following I had to add 'true' as well: return (validateEmail() && checkPostCode() && checkURL() && true);

Comment: It now works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/4UuVF/ you will get an error message of not found and that's because I didnt include and absolute link for process.php but other than that it works. I might need to improve the code a bit but I am pleased with that.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning a JSON string, so `r` could never possibly have a `.success` attribute. You're passing back a simple string, so maybe you'd better be off doing

```
if (r <> '') {
   alert('success');
} else {
   alert('failed');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution might be to store the information that you want to return in an array; and then use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on it before echoing it back.

Change the PHP portion of the AJAX script to be something like this:

```
$return = array();
$return['name'] = $_POST['f_name'];
$return['l_name'] = $_POST['l_name'];
$return['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$return['email_c'] = $_POST['email_c'];
$return['tel'] = $_POST['tel'];
$return['postcode'] = $_POST['postcode'];
$return['url'] = $_POST['url'];
$return['checkbox'] = $_POST['checkbox'];
$return['success'] = true;

echo json_encode($return);
```

And that will send the information back to jquery in a format that will be accesible to you in the form of r.nameofparam...so you would access the value of success with

*r.success*

or the value of url with

*r.url*

Answer (score 0):

Try use done & fail :

```
// AJAX call
$.ajax({
 url: 'process.php',
 type: "post",
 data: data
}).done(function() { alert("passed"); })
.fail(function() { alert("failed"); });
```